# specifies the number of integer in a field

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm doing a sign up form page where I should put also a "telephone" input but i need the telephone field to be 8 digits!!! if a user put a number more or less than 8 digits the signup form tells him an error.

it should be like this i think...
after connecting to DB

```
  $telephone=$_POST['telephone'];
  ... 
  .... 
  if(empty($telephone)){ // **i think i should write smth here???**
  echo  "phone number not set, and should be 8 digits!!" ;
  }
  else{

  /* Now we will write a query to insert user details into database */
  $insert_user=mysql_query("INSERT INTO login (telephone) VALUES ('$telephone')");
```

i appreciate any help :) 
thank you

Comment: use strlen and ctype_digit to check the number..

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: not all telephone numbers are exactly 8 digits. So you shouldn't force it that strictly.

For sensible validation of phone numbers, there are a number of good answers in this thread: [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

On a personal note, you really shouldn't use more than one exclamation mark in production code. Reading a '!!' is somewhat... upsetting... to users and other developers alike.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that the input is X number of DIGITS only:

```
// replace everything that is not in the range 0-9
$telephone = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $telephone);
// now check the remaining length - for this example 8
if (strlen($telephone) != 8) {
    // throw your error code in here
} else { ...
```

That in mind, are you sure that 8 digits is all you want for phone numbers? No dash, comma or parens, no longer numbers (US/Canada numbers are 10, not counting international code), some countries have longer/shorter numbers.

But in terms of your question, as posted, the above 2 steps would meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to set the maxlength of a text input field.

```
<input maxlength="8">
```

to ensure you have at least 8 chars you use

```
if(strlen($telephone) != 8){ error.. }
```

additionally to verify you have received only numbers and not characters you can use

```
for($i=0; $i<8; $i++){
if{(ord($telephone[$i]>47)&&(ord$telephone[$i]<58)){ // its a number }
```

Comment: can you please explain more the last part of ur answer? thnx @Shooky

Comment: It should be pointed out that setting the 'maxlength=' attribute is only a convenience, not a substitute for additional validation on the server side, as users could easily send a request manually that ignores the max length specified there.